# What is wrong with the WHERE clause of my OUTER JOIN Query?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am joining tables: OLD and NEW

Table: OLD

```
Employee_Name   Status
Ann             Y
Bob             Y
Carol   
Doug            Y
Ellen   
Frank
```

Table: NEW

```
Employee_Name   Status
Ann             Y
Bob 
Carol   
Ellen   
Frank
```

I can get the output I want with this join:

```
SELECT Old.Employee_Name AS [OldName]
  ,New.Employee_Name AS [NewName]
  ,Old.Status AS [OldStatus]
  ,New.Status AS [NewStatus]
FROM Old
   FULL OUTER JOIN New ON Old.Employee_Name = New.Employee_Name
```

Which is:

```
OldName         NewName         OldStatus   NewStatus
Ann             Ann             Y           Y
Bob             Bob             Y   
Carol           Carol       
Doug                            Y   
Ellen           Ellen       
Frank           Frank
```

Now I want to add a filter to the query so that it only keeps rows where the new and old status are different.

If I try:

```
SELECT Old.Employee_Name AS [OldName]
  ,New.Employee_Name AS [NewName]
  ,Old.Status AS [OldStatus]
  ,New.Status AS [NewStatus]
FROM Old
   FULL OUTER JOIN New ON Old.Employee_Name = New.Employee_Name
WHERE Old.Status <> New.Status
```

...it doesn't give the proper output.

For this example I think it would give the output of:

```
OldName         NewName         NewStatus   OldStatus
Bob             Bob             Y
```

...and fail to return the line with Doug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either operator is `null` in a SQL statement, it will return null (no rows) for that row.  For example, if you do `a <> b` where `a = 1` and `b = null`, it will always return no rows, even though it `a` and `b` are not equivalent.

You need to change your query to something like this:

```
WHERE COALESCE(Old.Status, '') <> COALESCE(New.Status, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do an outer join, the non-matching rows have `NULL` values.  This is why you move conditions to the `on` clause from the `where` clause:

```
SELECT Old.Employee_Name AS [OldName],
       New.Employee_Name AS [NewName],
       Old.Status AS [OldStatus],
       New.Status AS [NewStatus]
FROM Old FULL OUTER JOIN
     New
     ON Old.Employee_Name = New.Employee_Name AND
        Old.Status <> New.Status;
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference?  `ON` and `WHERE` use the same comparison rules.  You're still comparing null to non-null which will cause a row not to be returned.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 . . . You don't seem to understand how outer joins work.  The `where` filters the results.  The `on` keeps all rows from each table, even when the condition evaluates to false.